# bigdecimal gem 1.4.1 fails to build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

Trying to get bigdecimal 1.4.1. or 1.3.5 to compile in a rails project. I get:

```
bobwalsh@iMac2021 webservices % gem install bigdecimal -v '1.3.5'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bigdecimal:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.5/ext/bigdecimal
/Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
checking for labs() in stdlib.h... yes
checking for llabs() in stdlib.h... yes
checking for finite() in math.h... yes
checking for isfinite() in math.h... no
checking for struct RRational in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_rational_num() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_rational_den() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_array_const_ptr() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_sym2str() in ruby.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.5/ext/bigdecimal
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20221229-75388-86psx7 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20221229-75388-86psx7 clean

current directory: /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.5/ext/bigdecimal
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20221229-75388-86psx7 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20221229-75388-86psx7
compiling bigdecimal.c
bigdecimal.c:366:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                       INT2NUM(p->MaxPrec*VpBaseFig()));
                       ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
bigdecimal.c:365:39: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    obj = rb_assoc_new(INT2NUM(p->Prec*VpBaseFig()),
                       ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
bigdecimal.c:439:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_check_safe_obj' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    rb_check_safe_obj(str);
    ^
bigdecimal.c:439:5: note: did you mean 'rb_check_safe_str'?
/Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/internal/core/rstring.h:383:6: note: 'rb_check_safe_str' declared here
void rb_check_safe_str(VALUE);
     ^
bigdecimal.c:2047:6: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_check_safe_obj' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            rb_check_safe_obj(f);
            ^
bigdecimal.c:2152:30: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    rb_ary_push(obj, INT2NUM(e));
                     ~~~~~~~ ^
bigdecimal.c:2165:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return INT2NUM(e);
           ~~~~~~~ ^
bigdecimal.c:2737:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    VALUE  nCur = INT2NUM(VpGetPrecLimit());
                  ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [bigdecimal.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/bobwalsh/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-21/3.1.0/bigdecimal-1.3.5/gem_make.out
```

What do I do to get this working?

Comment: It looks like you are using ruby 3? According to the gem's github page you need at least version 2.0.x or above for ruby versions above 2.7.

Comment: @Beartech's ref link: https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal#which-version-should-you-select